# What is the Hilbert transform of $e^{-jwt}$?

Tags: signal-processing

What is the Hilbert transform of $e^{-jwt}$ ? 
I know how to do it via convolution , but i am looking for a less formal, more intuitive explanation such as the phase shift it imparts

Comment: [Helpful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform)?

Comment: The Hilbert transform is the convolution with $pv(\frac1{\pi t})$  equivalently it is $F^{-1}(i\ sign(v) F(h))$. Here $F(h) = 2\pi \delta(v+\omega)$ so you are looking at $F^{-1}(2i\pi sign(v) \delta(v+\omega))=F^{-1}(-2i\pi \delta(v+\omega))=-i e^{-i\omega t}$